# Symfony DTO - как получить данные формы с другими именами

Tags: symfony, форма, dto

есть DTO объект, со свойством:

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 *
 * @Serializer\Type("string")
 */
private $vasyaName;
```

И этот vasyaName далее по коду много где используется.
Есть две формы, и в одной из них надо для этого поля использовать имя **petyaName**

Есть ли какие-то волшебные аннотации для DTO-шки, чтобы принимаемое на вход имя из формы маппилось на нужное мне?
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: это не ответственность dto, это ответственность формы.  Используйте `property-path` . 

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path

Comment: Вы можете переопределить ваш класс, указать там `@SerializedName("petyaName")` и относительно формы, использовать требуемый вам класс, тем самым задавая поведение с помощью наследования.